# Why does GitHub API commit object point to a pull request that does not contain the commit?

Tags: github, github-api

I created a script that, from a commit in a repository, tries to figure if it belongs to a pull request and, in that case, will return all commits in that pull request. Debugging the output, I found that some commit objects refer to a pull request, but the pull request object does not contain such commits.
Let me do a practical example:

In the **GitHub Repo**

`https://github.com/DemocracyClub/yournextrepresentative`

there is the commit

`0722309a9c242aac28d2cb33798abbd18b233aa0`

that belongs to the pull request

`https://github.com/DemocracyClub/yournextrepresentative/pull/55`

So, in the GitHub website seems to be all good. No reverts, no amends, no weird git functions that would create a mess in the git history.

So, **GitHub API** correctly identifies the pull request with the URL

`https://api.github.com/repos/DemocracyClub/yournextrepresentative/commits/0722309a9c242aac28d2cb33798abbd18b233aa0/pulls`

and gives me as link of PR's commits the following one:
`https://api.github.com/repos/DemocracyClub/yournextrepresentative/pulls/55/commits`

BUT if you look in that link, there is no reference to the commit

`0722309a9c242aac28d2cb33798abbd18b233aa0`

Any idea of why is this happening?

Comment: Some of these GitHub things are very mysterious. But they're all quite specific to GitHub itself: there's no general Git answer. (The bitbucket API is ... similar, but different enough that none of this works there.)